# Use C++ ATL COM without registration for communication between 32-bit and 64-bit processes

Tags: c++, winapi, com, atl

I need to call into a 64-bit COM server from a 32-bit client. Both C++.

In order to avoid registration, I use the ROT to publish the class factory.

The `IDispatch` interface is used from the client to avoid marshaling issues.

I get an error at the first attempt to call a server method:

> Error loading type library/DLL

```
CheckHR(driver.Invoke1(L"SetValue", &ret, &arg), "SetValue");
```

Why do I need a type library or proxy if I only use `IDispatch`?

All the code is below.

IDL:

```
import "unknwn.idl";
[
    object,
    uuid(C3498C72-22F8-477A-B8BF-A6BCE9DE0596),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    helpstring("IZebraServer Interface"),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IZebraServer : IDispatch
{
    [id(1), helpstring("method GetValue")] HRESULT GetValue([out, retval] int* pValue);
    [id(2), helpstring("method SetValue")] HRESULT SetValue(int value);
};

[
    uuid(1632C43C-7C08-451F-A341-A6486F0CE517),
    version(1.0),
]
library ZebraServer
{
    importlib("stdole32.tlb");
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

    [
        uuid(C2E745B1-6DA1-4DD4-AF10-5860182B66EF),
        helpstring("CZebraServer Class"),
    ]
    coclass CZebraServer
    {
        [default] interface IZebraServer;
    };
};
```

Here is the server code:

```
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <atlctl.h>
#include <comdef.h>

#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace ATL;

#include "ZebraServer_i.h"

inline void CheckHR(HRESULT hr, const char* msg)
{
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        return;

    USES_CONVERSION;
    _com_error error(hr);
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << msg << "::" << W2A(error.ErrorMessage());
    throw std::exception(ss.str().c_str());
}

DWORD RegisterObjectInROT(
    IUnknown* pUnknown)
{
    // create binding context object
    CComPtr<IBindCtx> pBindCtx;
    CheckHR(CreateBindCtx(0, &pBindCtx), "CreateBindCtx");

    // Get a pointer to the ROT
    CComPtr<IRunningObjectTable> pRot;
    CheckHR(pBindCtx->GetRunningObjectTable(&pRot), "Getting ROT");

    // Create a moniker for the object
    CComPtr<IMoniker> pMoniker;
    CheckHR(CreateClassMoniker(CLSID_CZebraServer, &pMoniker), "CreateClassMoniker");
    // Register the object in the ROT with the specified display name
    DWORD dwRegisterCookie{};
    CheckHR(pRot->Register(
        ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE, 
        pUnknown, 
        pMoniker, 
        &dwRegisterCookie), 
        "Register object");
    return dwRegisterCookie;
}

class ATL_NO_VTABLE CZebraServer : 
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CZebraServer, &CLSID_CZebraServer>,
    public IDispatchImpl<IZebraServer, &IID_IZebraServer, &LIBID_ZebraServer, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>
{
public:
    CZebraServer() {}

    DECLARE_NO_REGISTRY()

    BEGIN_COM_MAP(CZebraServer)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IZebraServer)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
    END_COM_MAP()

    // IZebraServer methods
    STDMETHOD(GetValue)(int* pVal)
    {
        *pVal = m_value;
        return S_OK;
    }

    STDMETHOD(SetValue)(int newVal)
    {
        m_value = newVal;
        return S_OK;
    }

private:
    int m_value = 0;
};

OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO(__uuidof(CZebraServer), CZebraServer)

class ATL_NO_VTABLE CZebraServerFactory :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CZebraServerFactory, &CLSID_CZebraServer>,
    public IClassFactory
{
public:
    CZebraServerFactory() {}

    DECLARE_NO_REGISTRY()

    BEGIN_COM_MAP(CZebraServerFactory)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IClassFactory)
    END_COM_MAP()

    // IClassFactory methods
    STDMETHOD(CreateInstance)(IUnknown* pUnkOuter, REFIID riid, void** ppv)
    {
        return CComCreator<CComObject<CZebraServer>>::CreateInstance(pUnkOuter, riid, ppv);
    }

    STDMETHOD(LockServer)(BOOL fLock);

};

OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO(CLSID_CZebraServer, CZebraServerFactory)

CComObject<CZebraServerFactory>* g_pFactoryObject;

class CZebraServerModule : public ATL::CAtlExeModuleT<CZebraServerModule>
{
public:
    DECLARE_NO_REGISTRY()
    DECLARE_LIBID(LIBID_ZebraServer)

    HRESULT PreMessageLoop(int nShowCmd)
    {
        try {
            
            CheckHR(ATL::CAtlExeModuleT<CZebraServerModule>::PreMessageLoop(nShowCmd), 
                "CAtlExeModuleT<CZebraServerModule>::PreMessageLoop");
 
            std::cout << "Server started" << std::endl;

            // Create an instance of the factory class
            CheckHR(CComObject<CZebraServerFactory>::CreateInstance(&g_pFactoryObject), 
                "Create Class Factory Instance");

            // Query for the IUnknown interface
            DWORD dwRegisterCookie = RegisterObjectInROT(g_pFactoryObject);

        }
        catch (std::exception& ex)
        {
            std::cout << ex.what();
            return S_FALSE;
        }
        return S_OK;
    }
};
CZebraServerModule g_module;

HRESULT CZebraServerFactory::LockServer(BOOL fLock)
{
    if (fLock)
        g_module.Lock();
    else
        g_module.Unlock();
    return S_OK;
}

extern "C" int WINAPI _tWinMain(
    HINSTANCE /*hInstance*/,
    HINSTANCE /*hPrevInstance*/, 
    LPTSTR /*lpCmdLine*/, 
    int nShowCmd)
{
    g_module.WinMain(nShowCmd);
}
```

Client :

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <sstream>        
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
 
#import "C:\\Sources\\misc\\Zebra\\x64\\Debug\\AAA_ZebraServer.exe"

using namespace std;
using namespace ATL;
  
inline void CheckHR(HRESULT hr, const char* msg)
{
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        return;

    USES_CONVERSION;
    _com_error error(hr);
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << msg << "::" << W2A(error.ErrorMessage());
    const auto& str = ss.str();
    throw std::exception(str.c_str());
}

class CComInitializer
{
public:
    CComInitializer()
    {
        CheckHR(CoInitialize(nullptr), "CoInitialize");
    }

    ~CComInitializer()
    {
        CoUninitialize();
    }
};

int main()
{
    try {
        CComInitializer coinit;

        // create binding context object
        CComPtr<IBindCtx> pBindCtx;
        CheckHR(CreateBindCtx(0, &pBindCtx), "CreateBindCtx");

        // Get a pointer to the ROT
        CComPtr<IRunningObjectTable> pRot;
        CheckHR(pBindCtx->GetRunningObjectTable(&pRot), "Get ROT");

        CComPtr<IMoniker> pMoniker;
        CheckHR(CreateClassMoniker(__uuidof(ZebraServer::CZebraServer), &pMoniker), "CreateClassMoniker");

        CComPtr<IUnknown> pUnknown;
        CheckHR(pRot->GetObject(pMoniker, &pUnknown), "pROT->GetObject");

        CComQIPtr<IClassFactory> pClassFactory(pUnknown);
        if (!pClassFactory)
            return 0;

        CComPtr<IDispatch> pDispatch;
        CheckHR(pClassFactory->CreateInstance(
            nullptr,IID_IDispatch,(void**)&pDispatch),
            "pClassFactory->CreateInstance");

        CComDispatchDriver driver(pDispatch);

        CComVariant ret, arg(100);
        CheckHR(driver.Invoke1(L"SetValue", &ret, &arg), "SetValue");
        CheckHR(driver.Invoke0(L"GetValue", &ret), "GetValue");
    }
    catch(...)
    {}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The server needs it, not the client.  A simple way to implement IDispatchImpl.  Embedding it in the server should not be a problem, but do make sure the registry entries are available for 32-bit clients as well.

Comment: *Why do I need typelibrary or proxy* - but how marshal data for call ? how generic windows system dll can know how marshal data for your function ? how many parameters and which types it have ? this info can be taked from tlb or need custom proxy for marshal

Comment: With the ROT, one other solution is to use/expose a Windows well known (with it's proxy/stub/tlb already registered) interface. I use IOleCommandTarget since it's pretty generic (it has in & out parameters and uses VARIANTs which let you pass basically anything that fits into a VARIANT) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/docobj/nf-docobj-iolecommandtarget-exec

Comment: The typelibary is needed by the oleautomation proxystub dll (oleaut32.dll). It reads the typelibrary to figure out what your interfaces look like and how is should marshall the (oleautomation compatible) datatypes (and to do reflection for automation interfaces). So it still needs to be build and registered. I usually make a seperate resource dll (32 and 64 bit!) for that and register those. (Or you can do something with manifests if you don't want to register at all). So yes the typelibrary is still needed. IDispatch/Dual interfaces are not, `[oleautomation]` on custom interfaces should be ok

Comment: If you want a totally registration free 32/64 interop/RPC mechanism, have a look at gRPC. I have 20+ years experience with COM and only a short time with gRPC. But gRPC seems to more easy to use and deploy (if you want to trade object oriented interfaces for functional ones).

Comment: I do not want to use registry at all.  IDispatch automation should not have a problem with marshaling of variant types

Comment: Every interface needs some proxy/stub for cross process (and depending on context, for cross STA thread) communication. An IDispatch one can be built dynamically (w/o a proxy/dll stub) by oleaut32.dll (used to be called the "universal marshaler") but for that it still needs a .TLB. If you don't want to register anything you can use an existing interface that already has one registered somewhere (hence my trick in above comment)

Comment: IOleCommandTarget is a great Idea I will try it now. But maybe I can load tlb from file in order for oleaut32.dll to be able to use it? Is there a way to feed ITypelib to iniversal marshaler?

Comment: If you implement IDispatch yourself, you can return an ITypeInfo when the system calls IDispatch::GetTypeInfo https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nf-oaidl-idispatch-gettypeinfo + GetTypeInfoCount  The ITypeInfo implementation can be retrieved from an ITypeLib (ITypeLib::GetTypeInfo). The ITypeLib can be created from a file using LoadTypeLib https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-loadtypelib. It's been a long time since I've used this, but I don't see why it couldn't work in theory (by default the whole mechanism tries to read the registry).

Comment: @Simon Mourier  Your idea to use IOleCommandTarget worked well!.  I prefer to use IDispatch as it is easier to write.  I will try your idea with IDispatch now

Comment: @Hans Passant . You actually pointed me at the right direction. Default ATL implementation of IDispatch requires registry lookup on the server side. This was the reason it failed. So there are magic values to put as version numbers in to avoid this.    IDispatchImpl<IZebraServer, &IID_IZebraServer, &LIBID_ZebraServer, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF>  Now  everything works well. Can I accept both comments from you and Simon Mourier as answers?